# What does $\alpha+\gamma$ mean when $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are well-ordered sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, ordinals

I was asked to prove the following:

let $\gamma$ be a well ordered set with the following property: for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$  well ordered sets, if $\alpha+\gamma=\beta+\gamma$ then $\alpha=\beta$. Show that $\gamma$ is a finite set.

This might be a very doable question to solve, but I don't understand it. What does $\alpha+\gamma$ mean? they are not numbers, they are sets. What does this notation mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ordinals numbers **are** numbers. They have their addition and multiplication and even exponentiation.

The notation $\alpha+\gamma$ means that we take the ordinal $\alpha$ then we concatenate it with $\gamma$. Formally speaking, this is the only ordinal $\eta$ which is isomorphic to the lexicographic order on: $(\{0\}\times\alpha)\cup(\{1\}\times\gamma)$.

One can also define addition by induction. Let $s(\alpha)$ denote the successor ordinal of $\alpha$, then

1. $\alpha+0=\alpha$,
2. $\alpha+s(\beta)=s(\alpha+\beta)$,
3. $\alpha+\delta=\sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma<\delta\}$ when $\delta$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: I agree, but in our question, $\alpha$ was defined as a set, not an order type. Or I misunderstood something. Or maybe in spite of $\alpha$ being a set and $\gamma$ being a set, $\alpha+\gamma$ deals with their ordinals (even though ordinals are not mentioned)

Comment: I don't recall writing "order type" anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure about what it means for something to be a "number", but I upvoted both answers.

Comment: You said $\alpha$ for example is an ordinal. An ordinal is an order type of a well ordered set. This is not what was given to us in the question. We were given that $\alpha$ is a well ordered set. no mention of ordinals or order types.

Comment: Oria, you can think about ordinals are concrete well-ordered sets, not just order types. But sure enough, if you prefer to think about that like that...

Comment: @Carl: Numbers, for me, are abstract measurements of a certain quantities; and for numbers to "justify" their name they should carry some basic arithmetic as well. Ordinals represent the length of the line to the gate in Cantor's paradise.

Comment: That was beautiful Asaf.

Comment: @Oria: Shucks...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would you please comment on the solution I wrote under Cameron Buie's answer?

Answer (score 6):

Given well-ordered sets $\alpha$ and $\gamma,$ the set $\alpha+\gamma$ is the disjoint union of $\alpha$ and $\gamma,$ ordered with all the elements of $\alpha$ first (in their given order), followed by all the elements of $\gamma$ (in their given order). This ordering is in fact a well-ordering of the disjoint union.

As a hint for how to prove it, suppose $\gamma$ is infinite, and consider the case that $\alpha$ is empty and $\beta$ is a singleton. You should be able to show that $\alpha+\gamma$ and $\beta+\gamma$ are order-isomorphic (so identical, in this context).

Comment: Oh you skunked me this time, because I was writing the inductive definition as well! Well played.

Comment: I thought about that, but opted against the digression. (Also, typing with my thumbs is a pain.)

Comment: @Cameron Suppose $\gamma=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...\}$ with the order such that $a_i\leq a_j$ for all $i \leq j$. suppose $\alpha=\emptyset$, and $\beta=\{a_0\}$. $\alpha+\gamma=0+\gamma=\gamma$. $\beta+\gamma=\{a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...\}$. this set is order-ismorphic to $\gamma$ and as such, their ordinals are the same, so we get $\alpha+\gamma=\beta+\gamma$ and $\alpha \neq \beta$ and so $\gamma$ is finite. Correct? edit: $f(a_i)=a_{i-1}$ is an example of such order perserving isomorphism.

Comment: @Oria: Looks about right.

Comment: @Oria: Very close. What you have shown is that if $\gamma$ is infinite, then there exist distinct $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha+\gamma=\beta+\gamma.$ This is the contrapositive (so equivalent to) the proposition you're trying to prove.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is infinite, then what we know to be true about $\gamma$ turns out to be false. So the premise that $\gamma$ is infinite is false.

Comment: @Oria: Ah, I see your intent, now. You can certainly use a proof by contradiction, instead.